# How to search data by selecting month from firestore in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image]I saved data to firestore with DateTime.now. I fethed those data with stream builder. Now I need to search or filter data by month or week. Tried some method but no success. Can anyone help me with some that query.
how can I work with variables in "2021-04-01". This is not taking any int. so I cann't select a month or year from a dropdown.
Thanks in advance.

```
 var start = DateTime.parse("2021-04-01");
var end = DateTime.parse("2021-04-30");

FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("AllFarm")
        .doc("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
        .collection("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("Deposit")
        .where('date', isGreaterThan: start)
        .where('date', isLessThan: end)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.where()` for querying data stored on FireStore. Here is an example for you.

```
var start = DateTime.parse("2021-04-01");
var end = DateTime.parse("2021-04-30");

FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("AllFarm")
        .doc("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
        .collection("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
        .doc(docID)
        .collection("Deposit")
        .where('date', isGreaterThan: start)
        .where('date', isLessThan: end)
        .orderBy('date', descending: true)
        .snapshots(),
```

You just need to put your dates in here

Comment: Thanks for your answer . But how can I work with variables in "2021-04-01". This is not taking any int. so I cann't select a month or year from a dropdown. can you help me with that.

Comment: @MirFahimRahman you just need to parse DateTime object with input data from your user.

Comment: can you give an example . I didn't get it.

Comment: @MirFahimRahman sure, you can add it to the OP, I will update my answer then

Comment: Added to OP brother.

Answer (score 0):

Refer more on flutterfire here https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#filtering

Use the `where` clause inorder to do a basic search that meets your query

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("AllFarm")
          .doc("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
          .collection("${Variables.collectionNameID}")
          .doc(docID)
          .collection("Deposit")
          .where('month', isEqualTo: 'April')
          .snapshots(),
```

Comment: I have no month field in firestore. I saved data with DateTime.now. So how I can access month ?